# Regex help needed for user registration system?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to create a regex for user registration, wherein the length is greater than 6, where the passed string can have letters, numbers but only 1 hyphen and no other symbol. Also, the username should not end with a hypen and always start with a letter.

So far, I have done this:

```
^[a-z A-Z]+(-[a-z A-Z]+)?$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z].{6})[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/UNr2fD/1). `(?=[a-zA-Z].{6})` makes sure the  name starts with a letter and then has at least 6 chars. `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?` allows letters and digits, and only one optional hyphen, with no hyphen at the start and end.

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]                 any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .{6}                     any character except \n (6 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-9]+             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                           '0' to '9' (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z0-9]+             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                             'Z', '0' to '9' (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe this could work:

```
^(?!(.*-.*){2,})(?!.*-$)[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$
```

These are the parts:

- `^` matches the beginning of the string.
- `(?!(.*-.*){2,})` is a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that checks if there are more than two dashes.
- `(?!.*-$)` is a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that checks if the string ends with a dash.
- `[a-zA-Z]` matches a lowercase or uppercase letter as the first character of the string.
- `[-a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}` matches at least 6 characters which can include dashes, lowercase letters, uppercase letters or digits. These 6 characters complete at least 7 characters in the string including the first letter described in the part right above.
- `$` matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})` Positive lookahead, assert 7 chars at the right (greater than 6, or change to your requirements)
- `[a-zA-Z]` Match a char a-zA-Z
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ times a char a-zA-Z0-9
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `-[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match a single hyphen and 1+ times any of the listed
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/leNita/1)